# How to fix 'This Hollerith or character constant is too long' warning?

Tags: fortran, abaqus

I'm trying to add some features to an UMAT abaqus subroutine but the following warning is presented:

warning #6043: This Hollerith or character constant is too long and cannot be used in the current numeric context.

Since it's just a warning, the code runs, but not as expected.

I'm using abaqus 2017 standard compiler to run the subroutine, the warning mentioned is regarding the variable damagePath (below) it was declared as:
CHARACTER*80 damagePath

...

```
        IF (NPT==8) THEN

        pythonScriptPath = '/home/users/user/Documents/test/damage_model2.py'


        damagePath = '/home/users/user/Documents/test/damage.txt'

        command1 = 'python2.7 '//trim(pythonScriptPath)
        command2 = 'rm '//trim(outputPath1)

        CALL SYSTEM(command1)


        file_exists = .FALSE.


        DO WHILE (file_exists .NE. .TRUE.)

            CALL SLEEP(1)
            INQUIRE(FILE=damagePath, EXIST=file_exists)

        END DO


        OPEN(170, FILE=damagePath)

        READ(170,*) DAMAGE

        PRINT*, DAMAGE

        CLOSE(170)
```

...

Naturally, I have tried to shorten the length of the variable but even using just the short local path, the same warning was thrown.

Comment: Which line does the compiler complain about?

Comment: The warning concerns the line: damagePath = '/home/users/anderson/Documents/test/damage.txt'

Comment: Please show a complete example, reduce the code as much as possible and recompile. Make a small piece of code that shows the error and ppst the complete code here. See [mcve]. In your current incomplete code the error message does not make a good sense (at least to me).

Comment: In F77, the default line length is 72.  The line in question finishes at column 80.  Everything after column 72 is ignored so tt is missing a terminator.  I don't have an abaqus compiler so I can't tell you whether there is an option to increase the line length.

Comment: @cup Thank you for the reply, I was aware of that, but what really confuses me is that the variable right above, `pythonScriptPath` is even lengthier, but not warning is raised. I also tried only the local path, which is quite short, but the warning remains.

Comment: @VladimirF, Thank you, in this particular case though is really hard to simplify too much, the pattern for umat subroutines is very stringent and a minimal reproducible example would still be quite a block of code

Comment: Then *at least* we need the declarations of all variables and other entities that appear in your code. Notice the compiler complains about a *numeric* context. That should be some hint. Check that the variable is not used anywhere else. Check that the  string is not assigned into some numerical variable. Check that it does not happen to some other string.

Comment: It is not the length of the variable name.  It is the length of the line.  If you wish to keep the compiler flags as standard, use a continuation line for the rest of the string